# npm install takes forever and doesn't install engine.io

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, npm

I'm trying to locally install this package from Github: https://github.com/msalom28/Larasocial

The installation instructions are very clear, however, I'm getting stuck on `npm install` - it just hangs there for hours. I have tried everything, from rebooting my machine, to updating nodejs and `npm install -g sails` - nothing works.

This is the output so far.

> C:\wamp\www\socialnet>npm install npm WARN package.json
>   Larasocial@1.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN deprecated
>   gulp-clean-css@1.0.2: unnecessary duplicate of gulp-minify-css\
>
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\wamp\www\socialnet\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
>
> C:\wamp\www\socialnet\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>if
>   not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )else (rebuild)
>
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\wamp\www\socialnet\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
>
> C:\wamp\www\socialnet\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>if
>   not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (rebuild)-

Comment: What happens if you try `npm install socket.io` on its own?

Comment: It installs just fine that way. Should I open package.json and install all dependencies manually?

Comment: You could try this, but this makes me think socket.io and engine.io are installing fine, and it's some subsequent step that is causing npm install to stall.

Comment: What else can I do? I have already removed nodejs and reinstalled the newest version. Still no change.

Comment: Do you have the lastest version of npm?  Also, are Python 2.x and a Visual Studio version installed and available to node-gyp?

Comment: Why this question is tagged with Laravel?